# How can I re-size partitions

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I have 3 partitions one is "/" then a swap and lastly a "home". I was hoping to have the root only have the Ubuntu OS. (no dual boot only Linux)

The root is taking ALL the data, updates, and apps that I'm downloading to use. I only gave the root 8G to use for the OS, 4G for the swap and the rest of the 1T Hard drive was gonna be for everything else. I've been using gparted however it is not letting me re-size any of the partitions.

I don't want to reformat the hard drive but if I do have to I will.

Any help would be awesome.

Thanks
Adam

Answer (score 1):

Boot from Ubuntu LiveUSB and gparted will let you resize partitions.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @qbu Yes, it does provide an answer to the question.

Comment: @AdamH: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**